# jar: not found while trying to run jar

Tags: java

Using the book "Learn to program with minecraft plugins".

Trying to run build.sh through the busybox shell for cmd.exe on windows 10

Run into the error ./build.sh: line 46: jar: not found

I'm wondering what I'm missing, as I've followed the tutorial exactly, although it might just be that everything is out of date.

```
#!/bin/sh
#---
# Excerpted from "Learn to Program with Minecraft Plugins, CanaryMod Edition",
# published by The Pragmatic Bookshelf.
# Copyrights apply to this code. It may not be used to create training material, 
# courses, books, articles, and the like. Contact us if you are in doubt.
# We make no guarantees that this code is fit for any purpose. 
# Visit http://www.pragmaticprogrammer.com/titles/ahmine2 for more book information.
#---

# Set the variable MCSERVER to $HOME/Desktop/server,
# unless it's already set in the environment.
# To set it here explicitly, use MCSERVER=your_directory instead of 
# this next line.
: ${MCSERVER:="$HOME/Desktop/server"}

MODS="$MCSERVER"/CanaryMod.jar

# Make sure that the library jar
# exists and is readable
if [ ! -e "$MODS" ]; then
    echo "$MODS doesn't seem to exist.  Make sure you have CanaryMod.jar installed at $MCSERVER and run again.  If your server is not at $MCSERVER, set your MCSERVER environment variable to point to the correct directory."
    exit 1
fi

# Make the build directories if they aren't there.
# Throw away any error if they are.
mkdir bin 2>/dev/null
mkdir dist 2>/dev/null

# Remove any previous build products
rm -f bin/*/*.class
rm -f dist/*.jar

# Get the name of this plugin
# from the directory it's in
HERE=`pwd`
NAME=`basename "$HERE"`

# 1. Compile
echo "Compiling with javac..."
javac -Xlint:deprecation src/*/*.java -d bin -classpath "$MODS" -sourcepath src -g:lines,vars,source || exit 2

# 2. Build the jar
echo "Creating jar file..."
jar -cf dist/"$NAME.jar" *.inf -C bin . || exit 3

# 3. Copy to server
echo "Deploying jar to $MCSERVER/plugins..."
test ! -d "$MCSERVER/plugins" && mkdir "$MCSERVER/plugins" 
cp dist/$NAME.jar "$MCSERVER"/plugins || exit 4

echo "Completed Successfully."
```

edit: just now I tried another method for testing the jar command simply making a class file and trying to compile it into a jar file on the desktop

```
jar -cvf MyJarFile.jar CreateAJarFile.class
```

I still have the same issue

sh: jar: not found

edit:
I'm using a shell to run commands using busybox.exe that I've renamed as sh.exe and using a shell.bat file

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c sh.exe -l
```

Comment: This is a shell script and wouldn't work for Windows machine unless you are using WSL.

Comment: I'm running through a shell.

Comment: Do you have the java JDK? and if you do, is the `/bin/` directory for the jdk on your PATH Environment variable?

Comment: thank you I think I had seen that as a solution but it didn't click at first

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not having the PATH variable for Java /bin/ directory in environmental variables.

I ran the original build.sh again and this worked

Thanks to suggestion from user SaleemKhair